# Ionic android build - android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to learn Ionic.So far I have just created an app and added the android platform to it. But when I try to run the `build` command, I get the following error.

```
Command failed with exit code 1 Error output - 
/path-to-sdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

`ionic info` command outputs

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 3.13
Node Version: v7.0.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

My node version is 7.0.0

can you please point me what might have went wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, updated to the latest version of the build tools (25.0.2) and it worked!